# Badge and accept activities in global profile timestamped with user's date of registration

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

In [the global profile's activity tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/851/jeremy-banks?tab=activity), all "badge" and "accept" events are timestamped with (and sorted by) the user's date of registration on the associated site:

[image] [image]

<sup><sup>This was very confusing.</sup></sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice investigative work, you're absolutely right.

After a recent attempting at optimizing the network activity query, we were selecting the wrong `CreationDate` column out of the database as the activity's creation date.

This is fixed now.